# How can I create a static header?

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

I'm new using StringBuilder. I want to do a only one header for my XLS and I don't know how.
Here's my code:

```
    {
        StringBuilder csvcontent = new StringBuilder();
                
        csvcontent.AppendLine("Time" + ";" + "Close" + ";" + "Open" + ";" + "Low" + ";" + "High" + ";" + "Volume" + ";" + "SMA1" + ";" + "Label");
        csvcontent.AppendLine((Times[0][Shift].TimeOfDay + ";" + Close[Shift] + ";" + Open[Shift] + ";" + Low[Shift] + 
        ";" + High[Shift] + ";" + Volume[Shift] + ";" + SMA1[0] + ";" + Label));
                
        string csvpath = "D:\\xyz.csv";
        File.AppendAllText(csvpath, csvcontent.ToString());
    }
```

The first AppendLine will be the XLS header.
The result with that code is this:
[image]

Comment: What you've posted looks like a loop body - move the first two statements up outside the loop

Comment: Only create the header with columnnames if the file not exists previously. So do a File.Exists test on csvpath before and only add the header if that check is false. Currently you always appending one header and one dataline to the file.

Comment: I'd recommend to use a CSV Library, really.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen It isn't a loop I thought is the problem with AppendLine

Comment: No, AppendLine works as expected. Do you happen to call this in a loop?

Comment: @Fildor If I could I would be using CsvHelper but I don't know why I'm having problems with the DLL file.

Comment: @Fildor I don't using it in a loop and that's my doubt for what are happening here haha

Comment: If you are not using a loop, where do the multiple entries come from? Do you append to the same file in each run of the program?

Comment: ^^ If so, you may want to add the title line only if the file has been empty before. Otherwise only append the data part.

Comment: @Fildor I solved it using python with pandas